# Unable to use MongoDB C# driver with Hololens

Tags: c#, mongodb, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm trying to use `MongoDB C# driver (2.8.1)` in a `UWP` app built for `Hololens` using `Unity 2019.1.13f1`. I read that this driver (which targets `.NET 4.x` if I'm correct) was fully compatible with `UWP` apps since `Windows SDK 16299`.  However, even if it works like a charm in `Unity Editor`, it is not the case when deployed to `Hololens` (I cannot connect to my database).

I tried to build the project using `.NET 4.x API` compatibility level and I have granted the app all the necessary capabilities `(*InternetClient*, *InternetClientServer*, *PrivateNetworkClientServer*)`.

This triggered this exception on runtime : `Unsupported internal call for IL2CPP:Module::GetPEKind`

Then, I tried to change the API compatibility level to `.NET Standard 2.0`.

This made the above exception disappear but it still does not work...

Do you have any ideas? I might think that this driver is not compatible with `Hololens` after all...

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

After many attempts, I finally got to this conclusion:

- MongoDB C# Driver is currently (as of Unity 2019.1.13f1) not compatible with `IL2CPP` on Hololens because it tries to make an *icall* not supported by the latter (very specifically when trying to call `new MongoClient()`).
- I was unable to compile my project on Unity 2018.4 using `.NET` backend (apparently there are huge compatibility problems with this backend and this is why Unity is dropping it).

Honestly, I am not an expert on `UWP` at all, but as other people have managed to make this driver work as expected with IL2CPP on "normal" `UWP` devices, I am guessing that this could be related to Hololens software (I know it uses a special build of Windows 10).

Comment: Have you tried compiling using the .NET backend instead of IL2CPP?

Comment: @JuliaSchwarz That's a good suggestion! I'll try that and see if that makes it work. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it appears that Unity removed .NET scripting backend in version 2019.1 (the one I'm using), so I'll need to find another solution...

Comment: Just make a quick test to deploy a UWP app developed by Visual Studio which using MongoDB to HoloLens and it works well for me. Does a normal UWP work on your side?

Comment: Yes a normal UWP works fine and my app works fine except for the MongoDB part. I'm thinking that this could be something to do with the IL2CPP backend that Unity uses...

Comment: Okay so, after a few more trials with API compatibility level set to `.NET standard 2.0` or to `.NET 4.x`, I'm still getting the `NotSupportedException` thrown by MongoDB driver no matter what. I am going to downgrade my project to Unity 2018.4 (which is still shipped with `.NET backend` support) and see if things get better.

Comment: What's the status of this issue now? In-addition, when I mentioned the normal UWP, it means that can you run the UWP app with MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tinkering I found a way to make the MongoDB C# Driver work with Unity IL2CPP builds (I tested it on PC and UWP builds, but I guess it works for others too)
For it to work I had to make a custom build of the driver, plus pay some attention to other details.
But before I go into a bit of detail of my findings, here's a link to an example project that I uploaded: [MongoDB IL2CPP Example Project](https://github.com/SteepSheep/MongoDB-IL2CPP) (don't forget to change the MongoDBTester.cs to use your instance of MongoDB)

So here's what I did:

MongoDB Driver:
In **ClientDocumentHelper.cs** of the driver source is a function **CreateOSDocument()** which contains a section **#if NET452** - I just removed that whole section and tried it out in Unity with the IL2CPP build and it solved the OPs **NotSupportedException**

Unity - Assembly Stripping:
The stripping process removed some code that is actually needed, which I fixed with a linker file - **link.xml** in the Plugins Folder of my example project.

Unity - AOT and Reflections:
The MongoDB Driver uses reflections for some things, like getting the right serializer for a collection. The AOT nature of C++ builds and the way IL2CPP works don't mix well with that (see [Unity Docs - Scripting Restrictions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRestrictions.html)).
Fortunately this is easy enough to work around: If you use generic classes (like Dictionary) you need to specify the Serializer with the **BsonSerializerAttribute**
For constructors the same issue happens when using constructors with arguments - I just ensure that an **zero argument public constructor** is available for all classes that are used with MongoDB.

Unity - IPv4:
I'm not sure if this has anything to do with Unity or the MongoDB Driver, or maybe just the server why my instance of MongoDB was hosted, but I encountered a problem that my address protocol was not supported. So I wrote a workaround to use **IPv4** instead.

Additional Note:
I noticed that auto-mapping of my classes did not always work. I haven't quite figured out when and why it doesn't work but if this happens just manually map the class with **BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap**

Hope this helps, let me know if it works for you or if you encounter any other problems.